# How to access the form elements without knowing form Id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several form in my jsp with same UI but id is different.

I want to edit a particular form and submit those form elements through Jquery script.

I have js file below:

```
  $("form").submit(function(event){
    var id= $(this).attr("id");

    var name="#"+id;
    alert(name);
    var dis = $(name).attr("disabled");

    if (dis==true){
        alert("disabled");
        event.preventView()
    } else{
        alert("not disabled");
       //submit the form
    }
```

Here I am getting **dis**  as undefined.
so I every time condition goes false.
My requirement is

- if all input fields are disable state then dont submit form
- if all input fields are enable state then submit form

How can I achieve this. Where am I wrong ?

Can you please suggest.

Comment: what if one input is enabled not all

Comment: @ArunPJohny we are putting disable attr in all the input fields statically on the page. so it is guaranted that all fields are in disable state.

Answer (score 1):

You can check [:disabled](http://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/) selector along with :[not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
$("form").submit(function (event) {
    if ($(this).find('input:not(:disabled)').length==0) {
        event.preventDefault()
    }
})
```

Comment: It worked. I was closed enough but you made it perfect. Thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below function with all your requirement.

```
function chkvalidform(formID){
    var flag = '';
        formID = '#'+formID;
        $( ':input[required]:visible,select[required]:visible option[value]:selected', formID ).each( function () {
            if ( this.value.trim() !== '' ) {
                if($(formID+' '+'select[required].length > 0') && $(formID+' '+'select[required] option[value]:selected').val() == ''){ 
                    flag = 'false';
                }
                else {
                    flag = 'true';
                }
            }
            else { 
                flag = 'false';
            }
        });
        if(flag == 'true'){
                if (!$(formID).valid()) {
                    $(formID+' '+'input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled',true);
                    $(formID+' '+'input[type="submit"]').addClass('greySubmit');
                    $(formID+' '+'input[type="submit"]').removeClass('themeInBgColor');
                } else {
                    $(formID+' '+'input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled',false);
                    $(formID+' '+'input[type="submit"]').removeClass('greySubmit');
                    $(formID+' '+'input[type="submit"]').addClass('themeInBgColor');
                }
        }
        else  if(flag == 'false'){
                $(formID+' '+'input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled',true);
                $(formID+' '+'input[type="submit"]').addClass('greySubmit');
                $(formID+' '+'input[type="submit"]').removeClass('themeInBgColor');
        }
}
```

Comment: @student-17 recently I created this function for one of my project, so I shared with you, If you want `css` for above mentioed classes so that also I can provide.